# Call scope function inside onkeydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have the following html:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.show_value" ng-blur="update_show_value()">
```

A value (true / false) is fetched from the database and passed to the ng-model. Depending on it, the checkbox is checked / uncheked. The function inside ng-blur triggers the update in the database and works:

```
$scope.update_show_value() = function() {   
            if ($scope.user.show_value != undefined) {
                $scope.loading = true;
                //IF VALUE IS VALID, CALL THE UPDATEPIN FUNCTIONn
                User.updatevalue($scope.user)
                    //IF SUCCESSFUL, GET VALUE
                    .success(function(data) {
                        $scope.loading = false;
                        $scope.formData = {}; //CLEAR FORM SO THAT USER CAN ENTER NEW DATA
                        $scope.user.show_value = {type : $scope.user[0].show_value}; //PASS VALUE IN OUR SCOPE
                    });
            }
        };
```

The issue is that I would have to use the checkbox from other devices that don't support the click event. From these devices I should use the equivalent of enter (keycode 13). So I added the onkeydown event to detect when the enter key is being pressed on the checkbox. Using an example from w3schools, I see it works (here is the example http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_key_keycode3)

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.show_value" onkeydown="keyCode(event)" ng-blur="update_show_value()">
```

Now I want to call the update function when the onkeydown event detects that the code 13 was pressed. Something like this:

```
<script>
function keyCode(event) {
    var x = event.keyCode;
    if (x == 13) {
        alert ("You pressed the Escape key!");
        update_show_value();
    }
}
</script>
```

However, calling update_show_value inside the keycode function does not work. Actually, adding update_show_value inside the keycode function causes everything else not to work (ex. the alert)

So for some reason I think that scope functions cannot be called inside javascript functions. If that is true, is there a workaround?

Comment: Not the problem, but possibly the *next* problem: `keyCode` isn't reliable cross-browser. So: `var x = event.keyCode || event.which;`

Comment: I'd suggest to have a hidden element and trigger event manually. Your code is outside bounds of Angular and you will not get those function. An alternate can be polluting global scope but triggering event is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the scope object outside of Angular by using:

```
angular.element(event.target).scope(); // and then call whatever functions you want to on that scope object
```

You can define your own directive to handle keydown

```
angular.directive('myKeydown', [ function () {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            element.bind('keydown', function() {
                scope.update_show_value();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Or just use `ng-keydown` instead:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeydown :

```
$scope.keyCode = function($event) {
    . . . 
    $scope.update_show_value();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove () from $scope.update_show_value 
Try Below Code:

```
<script>
 var app=angular.module("myApp", []);
  app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.update_show_value = function() {
        alert(1);
    };

  });
</script>
```